# Join tables where no common field exists and based on ID columns

Tags: sql, oracle

This question seems hard to phrase, but after explaining my situation it should be easy to understand. I have two tables: one called INSTRUCTORS that holds instructor data and another called LIST_OPTION_ITEM that holds the ID values of different ID columns stored in the INSTRUCTORS table. A third and possibly important table to include is LIST_OPTION_TYPE, which contains the IDs of whatever ID column there is in INSTRUCTORS. Perhaps it would be easier to explain by showing sample data and my desired output.

**INSTRUCTORS**

| RANK_ID | SPECIALTY_ID | DUTY_TITLE_ID | SERVICE_BRANCH_ID | STATUS_ID | UNIT_ID | OFFICE_SYMBOL_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1354 | 319 | 931 | 2604 | 1378 | 1406 | 1429 |

**LIST_OPTION_ITEM**

| OPTION_ITEM_ID | OPTION_TYPE_ID | ITEM_VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1354 | 22 | CAPT |
| 319 | 20 | CBRN TRAUMA NURSE |
| 931 | 21 | IDMT-Squadron Medical Element |
| 2604 | 128 | 46N NURSE |
| 1378 | 23 | USA |
| 1406 | 24 | Guard |
| 1429 | 126 | CERFP |

**LIST_OPTION_TYPE**

| OPTION_TYPE_ID | OPTION_TYPE |
| --- | --- |
| 20 | Specialty |
| 21 | Duty_Title |
| 22 | Rank |
| 23 | Service_Branch |
| 24 | Status |
| 126 | Unit |
| 128 | Office_Symbol |

It is important to note that I cannot join INSTRUCTORS and LIST_OPTION_ITEM, as there is no common column. However, LIST_OPTION_ITEM and LIST_OPTION_TYPE can join on `OPTION_TYPE_ID`. My desired output from a `SELECT` query:

| Rank | Specialty | Duty Title | Service Branch | Status | Unit | Office Symbol |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CAPT | CBRN TRAUMA NURSE | IDMT-Squadron Medical Element | 46N NURSE | USA | Guard | CERFP |

I've tried some solutions but can't come up with anything. Do I need a cross join or something? Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Does it have to be a SQL statement?  The data model is terrible for performance.  Functionally, you could have a (decently sized) chunk of PL/SQL that dynamically builds the query and returns a `sys_refcursor`.  That's going to be a pain to maintain but will be much better than a pure SQL solution (and I'm not 100% sure a pure SQL solution is possible).  If you don't care about the column names in the result coming from the `list_option_type` table and you can just hard-code the column names in the query, that vastly simplifies the problem.

Comment: @JustinCave I understand the normalization and data model is poor, but it's just what my workplace has and requires. Since I wish to display the data on a webpage (I happen to be using ColdFusion), I do want to use an SQL query for this situation.

Comment: Can't ColdFusion call a stored procedure that returns a `sys_refcursor`?  What about (depending on the Oracle version) a pipelined table function?  How do you feel about hard coding the column names in the result rather than using the values in the `list_option_type` table?  Is that an option?

Comment: I've actually never heard of a `sys_refcursor`, although I am familiar with implicit and explicit cursors. I've also never used a pipelined table function, but that may be a good route based on the documentation I just viewed. Hard-coding is not an option, as there are around 1,000 records in the INSTRUCTORS table. I can start trying to use a pipelined table function, but if you have a good answer for this, I'd appreciate one.

Comment: One example of a pipelined table function that returns a dynamic result https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:4843682300346852395#5421020800346627246  If you're using 18c, that can be simplified quite a bit with a polymorphic table function https://oracle-base.com/articles/18c/polymorphic-table-functions-18c  Note that it doesn't matter how many rows are in `instructors`.  The hard-coding would be that the first column would be called `rank` rather than deriving the column name from looking at `list_option_type`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to do with Pivot and unpivot functions

below is sample sql:

```
with inst as (select inst_id, col, col_id 
from (select rownum as inst_id, a.* from instructor a)
unpivot
(col_id for col in (status_id as 'STATUS',rank_id as 'RANK',specialty_id as 'SPECIALTY',duty_title_id as 'DUTY_TITLE')
))
select * from 
(select inst_id,col,item_value from inst,
(select a.option_type,b.option_item_id,b.item_value from LIST_OPTION_TYPE a, list_option_id b
where a.option_type_id = b.option_type_id) opt
where inst.col = upper(option_type)
and option_item_id = col_id)
pivot
(max(item_value)
for col in ('STATUS','RANK','SPECIALTY','DUTY_TITLE')
) order by inst_id;
```

this will give desired output

Comment: Very nice! I like how you based the ID of the Instructors table on the row number, that way it returns the same number of records. Also a good practice of using UNPIVOT and then PIVOT.